# How to add an alpha directly on top of a square in latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, greek, scientific-notation

How can one add a $\alpha$ directly on top of a $\square$ in Latex.

Creating a symbol like this:

[image]

Comment: Try `$\overset{\alpha}{\square}$`

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\Square` of `wasysym` package you can obtain the inline `\square`. Also with the command `\stackrel{...}{...}` you can obtain the similar result of `\overset`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}


\begin{document}
$X\stackrel{\alpha}{\Square}Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `wasysym` package you can see the difference.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{wasysym}


\begin{document}
$X\stackrel{\alpha}{\square}Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]